# No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, exception, mockito

I wanted to get json response for exception in mockito unit testing.
This is my Application configuration file.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.spring")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

}
```

This is my exception class for existing user:

```
public class ConflictException extends RuntimeException{

    public ConflictException() {

    }

    public ConflictException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

This is my global exception controller class annotated with @ControllerAdvice.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandlerController extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{

    public GlobalExceptionHandlerController() {
        super();
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(ConflictException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> handleException(
            Exception exception, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ExceptionAttributes exceptionAttributes = new DefaultExceptionAttributes();
        Map<String, Object> responseBody = exceptionAttributes.getExceptionAttributes(exception, request, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>>(responseBody, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
}
```

Now, this is my controller test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@ActiveProfiles("Test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes={AppConfig.class})
public class UserControllerTest {

@InjectMocks
    private UserController userController;

    @Mock
     private UserService service;

private MockMvc mockMvc;


    @Before
     public void setup() {
         MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

         final ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver = new ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver();

            //here we need to setup a dummy application context that only registers the GlobalControllerExceptionHandler
            final StaticApplicationContext applicationContext = new StaticApplicationContext();
            applicationContext.registerBeanDefinition("advice", new RootBeanDefinition(GlobalExceptionHandlerController.class, null, null));

            //set the application context of the resolver to the dummy application context we just created
            exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

            //needed in order to force the exception resolver to update it's internal caches
            exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.afterPropertiesSet();


         mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(userController).setHandlerExceptionResolvers(exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver).build();

     }

@Test
    public void createUserExistsTest() throws Exception {

        when(service.createUser(any(User.class))).thenThrow(new ConflictException("User exists."));

        mockMvc.perform(post("/user")
                .content("{\"username\": \"bimal\", \"password\": \"check\", \"email\": \"test@gmail.com\", \"maxCaloriesPerDay\": \"1000\"}")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isConflict());  
    }
}
```

When I run my test method, I get following error:

ERROR:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> com.spring.app.exception.GlobalExceptionHandlerController.handleException(java.lang.Exception,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.LinkedHashMap
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:68)
```

How can I resolve this error? Exception is thrown but I cannot convert and use it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm over a year too late on this one, but for future reference this solved the problem for me.

The problem is that your exception resolver is not aware of any message converters, since you are providing it with a static application context.

It can be solved by the following code, directly below `exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext)`:

```
exceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.setMessageConverters(
    Collections.singletonList(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(new ObjectMapper()))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is being handled. This error refers to no HttpMessageConverter for the response entity type.  Add a JacksonHttpMessageConverter to the spring context.

Override this method from WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  in your AppConfig:

```
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter> converters) {
        messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
```

Comment: I added that but still I am getting "No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.LinkedHashMap" error. How to customize MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter for handling LinkedHashMap?